# String comparison in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have this registration form

```
    <form method="post" action="Register">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"/><br>
        <span id="taken">This email is already taken!</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />  <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" id="button"/>
    </form>
```

And this JS code is supposed to check whether the email exists in the database or not by calling a servlet using AJAX when focus leaves the email textarea.

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> var field = $("#email");
>
> ```
>         $(field).focusout(function(){
>               var email = $(field).val();
>
>                 $.get("Verify",{"email":email},function(data){
>                  alert(data);
>                     if(data=="true")
>                         $("#taken").css("display","block");
>
>                     if(data=="false")
>                         $("#taken").css("display","none");
>
>
>                 });
>          }); });
> ```

The servlet is returning the correct result (the code works until alert(data)) which is a String that's either "true" or "false", I checked that it's a String by alerting "typeof data".
What I want is to display the span $("#taken") if the AJAX response (data) was equal to "true" and hide it otherwise.
My problem is that the comparison is not working!
I've tried using "===" instead of "==" and I have also tried converting data to boolean by using

> var existed = Boolean(data);

to use to use "if(existed)" and "if(!existed)" instead of comparing strings

Nothing worked! I know the answer must be silly but I have truly spent the last two hours looking into it and nothing I have tried worked out. Please help.

Comment: Have you logged the exact string that the server returns?

Comment: Yes, the response was correct but the comparison didn't work.

Comment: You probably should not tell the user that the email already exists in your system.  This is really considered a security no-no, as by doing this, you give a potential attacker half of the information they may need to exploit your system.

Comment: @MikeBrant How do you suggest I inform the user that s/he cannot register using this email instead?

Comment: @RubaRamm Most applications simply reply with a more generic "account cannot be created" message, with instructions that they may try again with different username/password combination.

Comment: @MikeBrant Alright, I will follow your advice. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` 
And then change your code to

```
 if(data)
       $("#taken").css("display","block");
 } else {
       $("#taken").css("display","none");
 }
```

You also better add `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header to the response from the server

The reason it doesn't work for you is that `data` is boolean and when comparing it against a string,  the string is also converted to boolean,  and both`"true"` and `"false"` are converted to `TRUE` as they are non empty strings

`===` won't work as well because`data` and the strings differ in type so the comparison is always falsy

Comment: I used `typeof` to check data's type and it was String and the `content-type` was set to `text/html`, shouldn't the comparison have worked?

Comment: If it was exactly the same it should but it probably wasn't. .. maybe the string was `"true"` (with the quotation) or something like that